# How to deploy to Firebase hosting, with a URL?

Tags: firebase, deployment, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

1. Summarize the problem

I would like to provide contractors on a project, the ability to deploy to Firebase using only a URL (or cloud function).

When the URL is hit (browser, wget, curl), it would run a bash script, essentially do the following to deploy:

> 1. $git pull origin master    # a git repo would be setup in the function
> 2. $npm install
> 3. $ng build --prod
> 4. $firebase use
> 5. $firebase deploy

I am open to any/all ideas here on how to make deployment as simple as possible.  A CI/CD system is in the works, but for the moment, we would like to deploy by hitting a function.  Thank You!

2. Provide background including what you've already tried

I have done a lot of reading, searching around, but nothing that works for what I need so far, with regards to Firebase.